# Android java implement insert text after a button

Tags: android

I have a function to enter a value and choose a currency:

```
Currency = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
final EditText textEntercurrency = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textEntercurrency);
```

and I have a button that will send the event after pushing the button, how do I insert the text and Currency from the spinner to below button ? so it will be something like this :

```
setCode("") --> Here will be the Spinner options from the Currency....
setCode("USD")
setCode("EUR")
sendEvent(getApplicationContext(),"purchase","0.99");  --> Here will be "textEntercurrency "
sendEvent(getApplicationContext(),"purchase","12");
```

Example:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     switch (v.getId()) {
         case R.id.buttonreg:
             sendEvent(getApplicationContext(),"registration",""); 
             break;
         case R.id.buttonpur:
             setCode("") --> TO enter from Spinner
             sendEvent(getApplicationContext(),"purchase","");  -- "" to enter from textEntercurrency 
             break;
      }
```

Hope you can help me with my first project....

Thanks :)

Comment: what is sendEvent() method ? it is yours method right?

Comment: Can you post a bit more of your code? It's not clear at all what you already got working and what not.